# Creating a linear-gradient background overlay

Tags: css

I'm currently trying to create a `linear-gradient` using CSS.

The gradient should start all black on the left side and end with a lowered opacity in the middle. Now start with a lower opacity and end with normal opacity again on the right side.

My problem is the following:

I only get a good result using two different div elements.

**Example:**

```
<div style="float: left; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);"></div>
<div style="float: right; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 99%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 100%);"></div>
```

**My Question:**

How could I create the `linear-gradient` in one div element?

Screenshot outcome:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please, before come here and ask, do a proper research and e.g. read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: You can help yourself with this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: You also need to specify a height on your elements or you won't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

In your left div, change the 100% to be 50% and then copy the first rgba as your 100% state:

```html
<div style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69) 100%); height:20px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider multiple background:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),
    linear-gradient(to left,  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.69), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-position:left,right;
}
```